# Curl syntax to use to promote artefacts from Snapshot to Release Repository

Tags: maven, curl, nexus

Does anyone know the curl syntax to use to promote artefacts from Nexus Snapshot Repo to Release Repository please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **ABSOLUTELY** use curl for everything. I personally use the NING HttpClient (v1.8.16).

For whatever reason, Sonatype makes it *incredibly* difficulty to figure out what the correct URLs, headers, and payloads are supposed to be; and I had to sniff the traffic and guess... There are some *barely* useful blogs/documentation there, however it is either irrelevant to `oss.sonatype.org`, or it's XML based (and I found out it doesn't even work). Crap documentation on their part, IMHO, and hopefully future seekers can find this answer useful.

I don't think you can go from SNAPSHOT to RELEASE without generating another build, however if you create another build and deploy directly to the staging repo and promote from staging -> release, this will accomplish what I think you want.

If you release to Nexus other than oss.sonatype.org, just replace it with whatever the correct host is.

The URL that you are interested in 
`"https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/profiles/" + profile + "/finish"`

Where `profile` is your sonatype/nexus profileID (such as `4364f3bbaf163`) from when you uploaded your initial POM/Jar.

Here is the (CC0 licensed) code I wrote to accomplish this. The `repo` (such as `comdorkbox-1003`) is also parsed from the response when you upload your initial POM/Jar.

Close repo:

```
/**
 * Closes the repo and (the server) will verify everything is correct.
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static
String closeRepo(final String authInfo, final String profile, final String repo, final String nameAndVersion) throws IOException {

    String repoInfo = "{'data':{'stagedRepositoryId':'" + repo + "','description':'Closing " + nameAndVersion + "'}}";
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder("POST");
    Request request = builder.setUrl("https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/profiles/" + profile + "/finish")
                             .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                             .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo)

                             .setBody(repoInfo.getBytes(OS.UTF_8))

                             .build();

    return sendHttpRequest(request);
}
```

Promote repo:

```
/**
 * Promotes (ie: release) the repo. Make sure to drop when done
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static
String promoteRepo(final String authInfo, final String profile, final String repo, final String nameAndVersion) throws IOException {

    String repoInfo = "{'data':{'stagedRepositoryId':'" + repo + "','description':'Promoting " + nameAndVersion + "'}}";
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder("POST");
    Request request = builder.setUrl("https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/profiles/" + profile + "/promote")
                     .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                     .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo)

                     .setBody(repoInfo.getBytes(OS.UTF_8))

                     .build();
    return sendHttpRequest(request);
}
```

Drop repo:

```
/**
 * Drops the repo
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static
String dropRepo(final String authInfo, final String profile, final String repo, final String nameAndVersion) throws IOException {

    String repoInfo = "{'data':{'stagedRepositoryId':'" + repo + "','description':'Dropping " + nameAndVersion + "'}}";
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder("POST");
    Request request = builder.setUrl("https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/profiles/" + profile + "/drop")
                     .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                     .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo)

                     .setBody(repoInfo.getBytes(OS.UTF_8))

                     .build();

    return sendHttpRequest(request);
}
```

Delete signature turds:

```
/**
 * Deletes the extra .asc.md5 and .asc.sh1 'turds' that show-up when you upload the signature file. And yes, 'turds' is from sonatype
 * themselves. See: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-4906
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static
void deleteSignatureTurds(final String authInfo, final String repo, final String groupId_asPath, final String name,
                          final String version, final File signatureFile)
                throws IOException {

    String delURL = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/" + repo + "/content/" +
                    groupId_asPath + "/" + name + "/" + version + "/" + signatureFile.getName();

    RequestBuilder builder;
    Request request;

    builder = new RequestBuilder("DELETE");
    request = builder.setUrl(delURL + ".sha1")
                     .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo)
                     .build();
    sendHttpRequest(request);

    builder = new RequestBuilder("DELETE");
    request = builder.setUrl(delURL + ".md5")
                     .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo)
                     .build();
    sendHttpRequest(request);
}
```

File uploads:

```
    public
    String upload(final File file, final String extension, String classification) throws IOException {

        final RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder("POST");
        final RequestBuilder requestBuilder = builder.setUrl(uploadURL);
        requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo)

                      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("r", repo))
                      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("g", groupId))
                      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("a", name))
                      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("v", version))
                      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("p", "jar"))
                      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("e", extension))
                      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("desc", description));


        if (classification != null) {
            requestBuilder.addBodyPart(new StringPart("c", classification));
        }

        requestBuilder.addBodyPart(new FilePart("file", file));
        final Request request = requestBuilder.build();

        return sendHttpRequest(request);
    }
```

**EDIT1:**

How to get the activity/status for a repo

```
/**
 * Gets the activity information for a repo. If there is a failure during verification/finish -- this will provide what it was.
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static
String activityForRepo(final String authInfo, final String repo) throws IOException {

    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder("GET");
    Request request = builder.setUrl("https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/repository/" + repo + "/activity")
                             .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                             .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo)

                             .build();

    return sendHttpRequest(request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing that.

Answer (score 1):

The staging suite of Nexus Pro allows you to promote release artifacts deployed to a temporary staging repository through multiple steps into a final release repository. There is a REST API for automating this, but you can also use the Nexus Staging Maven Plugin or the Ant Tasks. The [Staging chapter in the Nexus documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging.html) has more pointers for all that and more.

However it has nothing to do with promoting SNAPSHOT artifact to a release. This is generally seen as a bad practice since it requires POM file rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such thing. You need to change your pom files and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You have to perform a full release: `mvn release:prepare release:perform`.